# Is it possible to run a custom kernel that works with T-mobile wifi calling?

Tags: wi-fi, voip

I am interested in understanding if it is possible to install a very lean version of Android (to maximize performance) and maintain TMO wifi calling.  If you have had success using a custom kernel and configuring to work with TMO wifi calling please state this in your reply.